# Very Bad predictions while achieving high validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing

I have trained a model that achieved a validation accuracy of 96% and very low validation loss but when I test it on other images , the prediction accuracy is bad in comparaison with the validation one , I have tried to process the images in the validation and test phase with the same parameters but the issue is still occurring , any ideas how i can fix it

here is the code :

```
directory = '/Users/anastalib/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Banana2'

img_width, img_height = 100, 100

img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    validation_split=0.2
    , rescale=1. / 255, )

# test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                                  shuffle=True,
                                                  batch_size=16,
                                                  subset='training',
                                                  target_size=(img_width, img_height))

valid_generator = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                                  shuffle=False,
                                                  batch_size=16,
                                                  subset='validation',
                                                  target_size=(img_width, img_height))

resnet_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                                                  input_shape=(100, 100, 3),
                                                  pooling='avg',
                                                  weights='imagenet')
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
resnet_model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
resnet_model.summary()

resnet_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     metrics=['accuracy'])

t1 = time.time()
print(datetime.datetime.now())

history = resnet_model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=valid_generator,
                                     steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size,
                                     validation_steps=valid_generator.n // valid_generator.batch_size,
                                     epochs=5)

print("Training took %s seconds" % (time.time() - t1))

path = 'overripe.jpg'
img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(path, target_size=(100, 100))
x = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
# Rescale image.
x = x / 255.
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.vstack([x])
classes = resnet_model.predict(images, batch_size=10)

print(np.argmax(classes))
```

Comment: It seems that you have overfitting because its main symptoms are having a very low training error, having a training error much lower than test error and having a high variance. You may consider getting more data (if possible) or performing regularization. [Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/) are explained some regularization techniques with Deep Learning by means of the Keras library.

Comment: How different are the validation and test sets? Maybe the images are just too different.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe seems a case of poor generalizability and your training/validation data are not representative a real data.

What you can try is to pool validation and test data, split again, retrain the model and see if the metrics improve.

A possible explanation is that there is a bias in your dataset, so the model is not really learning but is looking for something specific. Here you can find a better description of the phenomenon: https://pair.withgoogle.com/explorables/saliency/?linkId=8403074

Generally speaking, you can solve with more data or other solutions specific to the use case (in my experience, with medical images, color normalization was particularly important, as a example).